# A lemma to the escape lemma (Lee' Intro to smooth manifolds Lemma 9.19)

Tags: general-topology, differential-geometry, differential-topology, smooth-manifolds, vector-fields

I am trying to prove the following lemma, that is used to prove the escape lemma (Lee's Intro to smooth manifolds  Lemma 9.19)

**Lemma**

Suppose
$X$ is a smooth vector field on a smooth manifold $M$ . Let $\gamma : J \to M$ a
maximum integral curve of $X$ such that $b := $sup$(J)$ is finite. Let $t_0 \in J$,
and $K \subseteq M$ compact. Suppose $\gamma([t_0, b)) \subseteq K$.

Suppose $U$ and $V$ are relatively compact open subsets of $M$ such that $K \subseteq
U$ and $\bar U \subseteq V$ . Let $\psi \in C^\infty(M )$ such that $\psi|_ \bar U \equiv 1$ and supp$(\psi) ⊂ V$ .

Prove that there is a $\varepsilon > 0$ such that $(t_0 − \varepsilon, b) \subseteq J$ and $\gamma|_{(t_0−\varepsilon,b)}$ an is an integral curve of $\psi X$.

**So I have no idea how to start, how can I prove this ?**

---

**The following proposition can be used**

**Proposition** Let $X$ be a smooth vector field on a smooth manifold $M$ . Let $p \in M$,
and $\gamma_p : J_p \to M$ the maximum integral curve of $X$ with $\gamma_p(0) = p$. Let
$\gamma : J \to M$ be another integral curve of $X$ with $\gamma(0) = p$. Then
$J \subseteq J_p$ and $\gamma = \gamma_p|_J$ .

Answer (score 0):

Hint: First show that there is an $\epsilon>0$ such that $(t_0-\epsilon,t-0]\subset J$ and  $\gamma(t_0-\epsilon,b)\subset U$. Then observe that by construction $X$ and $\psi X$ coincide on $U$ and use that $\gamma$ is an integral curve of $X$. (Maximality of $\gamma$ does not really play a role for the lemma.)

Comment: I've been stucked in then first thing for hours I am unsure if J is open or not. I think not in general right? If it were open I could just say that there is a (t0-\epsilon, t0 +\epsilon) open interval contained in it. On another hand,  if b=sup J, for every epsilon there is a t' in (b-epsilon, b), but then I am not using t0 and don't know how to relate it to that interval

Comment: I think that $J$ has to open, because $\gamma$ is maximal (so this is used in the end). Since there are local integral curves around each point, it can never happen that the interval for the maximal solution contains boundary points.

Comment: Could you take a look at the second part of this question? https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4821560/the-escape-lemma-lees-intro-to-smooth-manifolds-lemma-9-19?noredirect=1#comment10261984_4821560

Comment: I am not sure where your problems lie: You know that $\gamma|_{t_0-\epsilon,b)}$ is an integral curve for $\psi X$. Since $\psi X$ has compact support, its integral curves are defined for all times, so there is an extension $\tilde\gamma$ of this restriction to all of $\mathbb R$, which is an integral curve of $\psi X$. But by construction there has to be an open interval containing $(t_0-\epsilon,b])$ on which $\tilde\gamma$ has values in $U$, and there $X$ and $\psi X$ coincide. On this interval $\tilde\gamma$ extends $\gamma$ beyond $b$, which is a contradiction. The rest is technicalities.

Comment: By the way I reposted the question here https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4821934/how-do-i-prove-step-b-in-this-approach-to-the-prove-of-the-escape-lemma?noredirect=1&lq=1, making it specific that I needed help with step b and the contradiction.

Comment: The problem are a bit these techicalities. I don't see where are you using (a) and the proposition?