# How do I prove the escape lemma?

Tags: general-topology, differential-geometry, differential-topology, smooth-manifolds, vector-fields

I am trying to prove the the escape lemma (Lee's Intro to smooth manifolds  Lemma 9.19)
The proof can be broken down in three parts

a) First prove this lemma:

**Lemma**: $X$ is a smooth vector field on a smooth manifold $M$ . Let $\gamma : J \to M$ a
maximum integral curve of $X$ such that $b := $sup$(J)$ is finite. Let $t_0 \in J$,
and $K \subseteq M$ compact. Suppose $\gamma([t_0, b)) \subseteq K$.

Suppose $U$ and $V$ are relatively compact open subsets of $M$ such that $K \subseteq
U$ and $\bar U \subseteq V$ . Let $\psi \in C^\infty(M )$ such that $\psi|_ \bar U \equiv 1$ and supp$(\psi) ⊂ V$ .

Then there is a $\varepsilon > 0$ such that $(t_0 − \varepsilon, b) \subseteq J$ and $\gamma|_{(t_0−\varepsilon,b)}$ an is an integral curve of $\psi X$.

b) Let $\delta$ be the maximal integral curve of $\psi X$ so that  $\delta(t_0)=\gamma(t_0)$. Let $J_U \subseteq \Bbb R$ the connected component of $\delta^{-1}(U)$ that contains $t_0$. Prove that $[t_0, b]\subseteq J_U$

c) Derive a contradiction

Suppose step a is proven,  **How should I prove step b  and derive a contradiction **

---

**The following proposition can be used  twice in the whole proof**

**Proposition** Let $X$ be a smooth vector field on a smooth manifold $M$ . Let $p \in M$,
and $\gamma_p : J_p \to M$ the maximum integral curve of $X$ with $\gamma_p(0) = p$. Let
$\gamma : J \to M$ be another integral curve of $X$ with $\gamma(0) = p$. Then
$J \subseteq J_p$ and $\gamma = \gamma_p|_J$ .

Comment: I don't see (a), (b), (c) in his text like you write here. I think all you need to do to show the escape lemma is to show that for initial conditions in a compact set $K$, there is a uniform time of existence for solutions of the ODE. This would imply that you can extend the solution past time $b$, a contradiction. The uniform time of existence for vector fields on open subsets of $\mathbb{R}^n$ is a classical result which is often proven using the contraction mapping theorem, so I guess there is a simple way to prove it for manifolds.

Comment: @Kakashi In my lectures is broken down to help guiding the proof. In the text there is no proof at all of course

Answer (score 0):

See page 70 of https://mtaylor.web.unc.edu/wp-content/uploads/sites/16915/2018/04/analmv.pdf. It shows that if $\Omega \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ is open and $K \subset \Omega$ is compact, then there is a time $t_K > 0$ such that for all $x \in K$, the integral curve passing through $x$ exists on the interval $[-t_K, t_K]$.

Now turn to the case where $\Omega$ is a manifold. Then for each $x \in K$, we use coordinates to obtain a time of existence $t_x$ for points in a neighborhood of $x$. Then by covering $K$ by finitely many neighborhoods, we get a uniform time of existence for all points in $K$.