# How do I prove step b in this approach to the prove of the escape lemma

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-topology, smooth-manifolds

I am trying to prove the the escape lemma (Lee's Intro to smooth manifolds  Lemma 9.19)
The proof can be broken down in three parts

a) First prove this lemma:

**Lemma**: $X$ is a smooth vector field on a smooth manifold $M$ . Let $\gamma : J \to M$ a
maximum integral curve of $X$ such that $b := $sup$(J)$ is finite. Let $t_0 \in J$,
and $K \subseteq M$ compact. Suppose $\gamma([t_0, b)) \subseteq K$.

Suppose $U$ and $V$ are relatively compact open subsets of $M$ such that $K \subseteq
U$ and $\bar U \subseteq V$ . Let $\psi \in C^\infty(M )$ such that $\psi|_ \bar U \equiv 1$ and supp$(\psi) ⊂ V$ .

Then there is a $\varepsilon > 0$ such that $(t_0 − \varepsilon, b) \subseteq J$ and $\gamma|_{(t_0−\varepsilon,b)}$ an is an integral curve of $\psi X$.

b) Let $\delta$ be the maximal integral curve of $\psi X$ so that  $\delta(t_0)=\gamma(t_0)$. Let $J_U \subseteq \Bbb R$ the connected component of $\delta^{-1}(U)$ that contains $t_0$. Prove that $[t_0, b]\subseteq J_U$

c) Derive a contradiction

Suppose step a is proven,  **How should I prove step b  and derive a contradiction **

---

**The following proposition can be used  twice in the whole proof**

### **Proposition** Let $X$ be a smooth vector field on a smooth manifold $M$ . Let $p \in M$,
and $\gamma_p : J_p \to M$ the maximum integral curve of $X$ with $\gamma_p(0) = p$. Let
$\gamma : J \to M$ be another integral curve of $X$ with $\gamma(0) = p$. Then
$J \subseteq J_p$ and $\gamma = \gamma_p|_J$ .

Note I am reposting this question

[How do I prove the escape lemma?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4821560/how-do-i-prove-the-escape-lemma)

in which I mistankingly made people think I wanted any proof of the escape lemma, while my question is **HOW TO PROVE (b)**, using the lemma(a) and the  proposition, not how to prove the escape lemma in whatever way ignoring the whole post

Comment: This is the definition of a maximal integral curve.

Comment: @Didier Well since this proposition was also given to me as an exercise I guess there was be some other equivalent definition that is being taken as the definition. By the way, is this definition or proposition valid more generally for a $t_0$ instead of 0?

Comment: @Didie In Lee's book: A maximal integral curve is one that cannot be extended to an integral curve on any larger open interval. On the other hand in the proposition we have a priori two different curves, with just a point in common

Answer (score 1):

Step b) is just basic general topology and does not use much of the Lemma. $\delta^{-1}(U)\subset\mathbb R$ is open, hence a disjoint union of open intervals, one of which is $J_U$. By definition $t_0\in J_U$ and $(t_0-\epsilon,b]\subset \delta^{-1}(U)$ and since $ (t_0-\epsilon,b]$ is connected and contains $t_0$, we must have $(t_0-\epsilon,b]\subset J_U$. This of course implies $[t_0,b]\subset J_U$.